# how to disable closing of material-extended mde popover after clicking inside it

Tags: material-ui, angular6

I am adding a chatbot on a popover used by importing material extended mde popopver. But when I try to chat or click on the popover , the popover is closed , is there any true/false trigger , to prevent closing of popover after I click on it ? Any help is appreciated. I want to implement this in typescript, not javascript.

This is say xyz.component.html [This is what i have done so far. I am not able to chat here in this window as the popover window closes , immediately once I click on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xso8e.png)

```
  <button class="mdc-fab app-fab--absolute"  
     [mdePopoverTriggerFor]="appPopover"
      mdePopoverTriggerOn="click" aria-label="Favorite" mat-fab ><mat-icon>
     <span class="mdc-fab__icon material-icons">textsms</span> 
  </mat-icon></button>   

  <mde-popover #appPopover="mdePopover" [mdePopoverOverlapTrigger]="false"> 
       Hi this is the chatbot. 
  </mde-popover>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured how to do this, just add [mdePopoverCloseOnClick]="false" to disable click on close. As shown below

```
<button class="mdc-fab app-fab--absolute"  
 [mdePopoverTriggerFor]="appPopover"
  mdePopoverTriggerOn="click" aria-label="Favorite" mat-fab ><mat-icon>
 <span class="mdc-fab__icon material-icons">textsms</span> 
</mat-icon></button>   

<mde-popover #appPopover="mdePopover" [mdePopoverCloseOnClick]="false"  [mdePopoverOverlapTrigger]="false"> 
   Hi this is the chatbot. 
</mde-popover>
```

here is the link for more attributes
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-extended-mde-popover?file=app%2Fapp.component.html